# VirtualHost на Apache 2.4.6

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

Вопрос такой: необходимо на одной машине создать несколько виртуальных хостов.
Стоит Apache 2.4.6
Сначала хотел на отдельный порт повесить:

```
Listen 8881
<VirtualHost *:8881>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/mamp/apache2/hthosts/www1"
    <Directory "/Applications/mamp/apache2/hthosts/www1">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Выдет 403 ошибку нет прав, причем даже если запрашивал несуществующий файл.

Потом попробовал по именам:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName www.vhost1.local
    ServerAlias vhost1.local

    DocumentRoot "/Applications/mamp/apache2/hthosts/www1"
    <Directory "/Applications/mamp/apache2/hthosts/www1">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

При старте сервера выдает: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release
При запросе вообще не отвечает. Даже заголовки в ответ не посылает.
Кто нибудь знает как можно решить вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

403 исправляется в Apache 2.4 так:

```
<Directory /Applications/mamp/apache2/hthosts/www1>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```